# fabric.Image.fromURL is not being called in jest test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs in a reactjs application. I created canvas component and I want to test `componentDidMount` code where I call

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(
        imageFile.url,
        (loadedImage: fabric.Image) => {
            ...some code in here...
});
```

I am providing `imageFile` and loading an image from the url.
When I start the test, callback on image loaded is not being executed. Can anyone help?
I am not sure whether it has to do anything with jest or fabricjs...

Comment: You test may finish before callback called, have you followed this recommendation? - https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous

Comment: It would be best to mock out `fabric.Image` as your test is now reliant on having an internet connection. If you want to test your callback when the image is loaded  then don't inline the callback.

Comment: @Bulkan, any tutorial about it?

Comment: How did you solve this?